# How to get associative array from Stripe objects PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve the metadata and payment amount from an object retrieved from an endpoint using Stripe's PHP library.

I am using a very slightly modified version of their example code:

```
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        // Read the result.
        $paymentIntentValues = $paymentIntent->values(); // Returns standard array??
        break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
        // Read the result.
        $paymentMethodValues = $paymentMethod->values(); // Returns standard array??
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
}

http_response_code(200);
```

The problem is when I dump any of the objects, e.g. $paymentIntent, the dump is just of the Charge object and when I try get the values using ***values();*** it gives me an ambiguous standard array.

e.g.

```
array (45) [
    0 => string (12) "pi_secretkey"
    1 => string (12) "paymentIntent"
    2 => integer 247
    3 => integer 0
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => string (13) "anothersecret"
    8 => Stripe\StripeObject (7) (
        protected '_lastResponse' -> null
        protected '_opts' -> Stripe\Util\RequestOptions (3) (
            public 'apiBase' -> null
            public 'apiKey' -> null
            public 'headers' -> array (0) []
        )
```

I want to be able to read the values of that $paymentIntent object and use the values consistently either through associative array or object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve an associative array listing the values of Stripe objects, e.g. the PaymentIntent object, you must use the ***toArray()*** function

e.g.

```
// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        // Read the result.
        $paymentIntentValues = $paymentIntent->toArray(); // Returns associative array of values.
        break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
        // Read the result.
        $paymentMethodValues = $paymentMethod->toArray(); // Returns associative array of values.
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
}
```

result:

```
array (45) [
    'id' => string (12) "pi_secretkey"
    'object' => string (12) "paymentIntent"
    'amount' => integer 247
    'amount_refunded' => integer 0
    'application' => null
    'application_fee' => null
    'application_fee_amount' => null
    'balance_transaction' => string (13) "anothersecret"
    etc... etc...
```